# Why my SharedPreferences string value for login null when reopen the app?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-sharedpreferences, android-authenticator

I'm still new in android. I have created login app with android that user can login to the app. After user successfully login then direct to Home Activity. My preference value (I use email for string value) saved well and my logout button work well. I try to press Home button in my android device emulator then run app again, it works well. The app can restore my preference value in my Home activity with email displayed. My PROBLEM is when I press back button in my device emulator, the app closed and I try to open my app again, Home activity displayed but not load my preference value string (email) and not display email of the last logged in user. Can you tell me why? How to keep my preference value (email string) after user logged in to the app?

Here are my codes:
**SessionManager.java**

```
package com.agungphe.simplelogreg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SessionManager extends Activity {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "PirjaRSMS";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     *
     * @param email*/
    public void createLoginSession(String email){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

**Login.java**

```
package com.agungphe.simplelogreg;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://182.168.6.77/api_pirja/login.php";

    public static final String KEY_EMAIL="email";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";

    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin;

    private String email;
    private String password;

    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Session Manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if(session.isLoggedIn() == true){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
            editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }


    private void userLogin() {
        email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                            session.createLoginSession(email);
                            openHome();
                        }
                        else if(response.trim().equals("blm_aktif")){
                            openVerifikasi();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
                map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                return map;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void openHome(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void openVerifikasi(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Verifikasi.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        userLogin();
    }

    public void keRegister(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Home.java**

```
package com.agungphe.simplelogreg;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManager session;

    // Button Logout
    Button btnLogout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        session.checkLogin();

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        // email
        String email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        TextView lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblEmail);

        // Button logout
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        // displaying user data
        lblEmail.setText(email);

    }

    public void logOut(View view){
        session.logoutUser();
        finish();
     }
}
```

Thanks for advance :)

Comment: on which activity you are pressing back button @Agung ?

Answer (score -1):

Judging from the Android Lifecycle of an Activity,

[image]

Have you implemented an onPause and onResume method? Because pressing the back button will not close the activity, but it goes into a pause state. performing a setText in the onResume could solve your issue.

Here's your onResume:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // You'll have to run the code to retrieve your user details, and set all of them to their relative widgets.
}
```

Comment: where I can put onPause and onResume method? cna you give me example? thanks for your help

Comment: @Agung https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html Put it within your activity

Comment: Yes, I have read the page, but I'm still confused about what should I do in onPause and onResume. for example I want to keep my pref (string email) when I closed (maybe it is called paused). so how to implement that in onResume? in the page example is: 

if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

what is mCamera and release()?

Comment: @Agung That was sample code. Simply retrieve your session object's data and setText on the respective widgets within the onResume method.

Comment: I have tried this:    
public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        // email
        String email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);

        session.createLoginSession(email);
    }

Comment: public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        // email
        String email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        TextView lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblEmail);

        // Button logout
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        // displaying user data
        lblEmail.setText(email);
    }

Comment: but when I logged in and close the app (pressed back button) the open app again, it still null value :(

Comment: which activity did you close from? @Agung your onResume and onPause must be there

Comment: I try to close from Home Activity and I have put onResume and onPause there